# Can't use `:wqa` with open terminal buffers

Tags: neovim, terminal, save, quit

I have next problem: When I use `:term` buffers the `:wqa` command produces error:

[image]

Which is quite expected because terminal buffers isn't writable. BUT the `:wa` and `:q` separatly work.
This is strange.

To be sure I used next commands:

```
$ nvim -u NONE +term
:wqa
:wa
:q
```

Comment: If you're concerned about the extra keystokes just add a new command `command WQ wa | qa`

Answer (score 0):

Just do `:wa` and then `:qa`. This is because you can't write the buftype of terminal which you're trying to do when but `:wa` doesn't try to write the term buffer

Comment: I do know this, but I wont to make 7 keystrokes instead of 5. Actually, I think this is a bug, so there is no workaround.